# Integer Pattern

Tags: c++, substring, subset, subsequence

Below is how the solution should look like.

---

Enter Y : 239847239
Enter X : 847
X is substring of Y

Enter Y : 239847239
Enter X : 3923
X is subsequence of Y

Enter Y : 239847239
Enter X : 489
X is neither substring nor subsequence of Y

---

and below is my crude attempt at making the code:

```
int main() 
{

    cout << "Enter Y: ";
    vector <int> Y;
    int Y_number;
    cin >> Y_number;

    cout << "Enter X: ";
    vector <int> X;
    cin >> X;

    if (Y > X)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Y.size(); i++)
        {
            Y.push_back(Y_number);
            if (Y.size(i) == X.size(i))
            {

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "X is neither substring nor subsequence of Y";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format properly

Comment: There are a bunch of things here and you don't even describe a specific problem (which is also why this question is probably being closed). However, here's some advise: Firstly, separate input from the tests for the two properties by simply using functions. One function `bool is_substring(string const& s, string const& sub)` and another `bool is_subsequence(string const& s, string const& sub)`, who's implementation I'll leave to you. Splitting these off means you now have three (two functions plus the glue code connecting them) smaller problems, which you can each solve separately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Y, X, YY;
    cout << "Enter Y: ";
    cin >> Y;
    cout << "Enter X: ";
    cin >> X;
    YY = Y + Y;

    if (std::string::npos != Y.find(X)) {
        cout << "X is substring of Y" << endl;
    } else if (std::string::npos != YY.find(X)) {
        cout << "X is subsequence of Y" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "X is neither substring nor subsequence of Y" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: at least it generates the same results as your description.